# Stored Procedure taking longer than a normal query

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures, mysql-5.6, query-performance

I have a stored procedure which returning single but taking 16+ seconds when I call that but only .5 second, if I run that by normal query.

Procedure

```
    DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `local_db`.`getAllMatchedStockByCompany` $$
CREATE
    PROCEDURE `local_db`.`getAllMatchedStockByCompany`(
    IN Company_ID BIGINT(20)
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT t1.*
    FROM ((SELECT t2.SRTitle,t2.UrlPart,t2.ScheduledTime,t2.Photo,TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(fnStripTags(t2.SRDescription),'&nbsp;',''),' ',
            30), '\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\t', ''),'\r\n\t\r\n\t',''),'\r\n\t',''),'&rsquo;',''))AS Description, 'stock-research' AS from_tbl,t2.IsActive
           ,t2.CompanyID FROM t2
          ) UNION
          (SELECT t3.ReportTitle,t3.UrlPart,t3.CreatedDate,t3.ReportImage,TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(fnStripTags(t3.Description),'&nbsp;',''),' ',
                30),'\r\n\t\r\n\t',''),'&#39;','`')),IF(t3.SpecialReport = 1,'special-report','report'),t3.IsActive
        ,t3.CompanyID FROM t3
          )
         ) t1
         WHERE CompanyID = Company_ID AND IsActive = 1
         ORDER BY ScheduledTime DESC;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The total execution time of this is 16 seconds with 1 row.

If I use below query:

```
SELECT t1.*
    FROM ((SELECT t2.SRTitle,t2.UrlPart,t2.ScheduledTime,t2.Photo,TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(fnStripTags(t2.SRDescription),'&nbsp;',''),' ',
            30), '\r\n\t\r\n\r\n\t', ''),'\r\n\t\r\n\t',''),'\r\n\t',''),'&rsquo;',''))AS Description, 'stock-research' AS from_tbl,t2.IsActive
           ,t2.CompanyID FROM t2
          ) UNION
          (SELECT t3.ReportTitle,t3.UrlPart,t3.CreatedDate,t3.ReportImage,TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(fnStripTags(t3.Description),'&nbsp;',''),' ',
                30),'\r\n\t\r\n\t',''),'&#39;','`')),IF(t3.SpecialReport = 1,'special-report','report'),t3.IsActive
        ,t3.CompanyID FROM t3
          )
         ) t1
         WHERE CompanyID = 931 AND IsActive = 1
         ORDER BY ScheduledTime DESC;
```

It took only .5 to 1 seconds with one row.

Can anyone of you let me why this happening or how I can improve my SP execution time?

Answer (score 1):

- It is usually better to cleanse the data *before* inserting it into the database.
- The query can be sped up in both cases by some rearranging; see below.
- Is this the only difference? -- `CompanyID = 931` versus `CompanyID = Company_ID`
- Is `CompanyID` declared `BIGINT`?
- Can you get `EXPLAIN` output, both in the SP and outside, to help verify the theory that it is easier to work with a number than a parameter passed in.
- If you know that there will be no duplicates, use `UNION ALL`, which is faster.

By moving the `WHERE` into each `SELECT` but leaving the `ORDER BY outside, the query is likely to be faster:

```
( SELECT ... WHERE ... )
UNION [DISTINCT|ALL]
( SELECT ... WHERE ... )
ORDER BY ...
```

If the main problem is `931` versus `Company_ID`, then the solution may involve constructing the query and using `prepare` and `execute`.

Comment: [@Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james)
thanks for your answer.
1- Is this the only difference? -- CompanyID = 931 versus CompanyID = Company_ID-- Yes.
2- Is CompanyID declared BIGINT? Yes.
3- Actually I am using laravel, so  I am not able to user "fnStripTags" function to remove html code from description, So this is the reason, I am using SP over normal query.
I first create normal query than convert them in SP to get easily called in Laravel eloquent.

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes 3rd party packages make more trouble than benefit.